# Why is the boolean difference modifier not working on joined meshes?

Tags: mesh, modifiers

I have gotten the boolean difference modifier working on basic shapes, however, when it is applied on joined meshes (with correct normals and no duplicate vertices) [image: image-1] the boolean difference modifier applies a union instead of a difference [image: image-2]

Does anyone know what could be going wrong?

Comment: Objects with loose parts and boolean always produced problems in the past. Check out this answer to apply booleans to all objects of a collection as a workaround of loose part objects and booleans. https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/165372/multiple-holes-in-object-by-boolean/165380#165380

Answer (score 0):

I notice you're using Blender 2.90.x. I don't have that, I'm still using 2.83.4 and 2.91.
That said, I made an "O" by scaling a cube, and then making 3 duplicates with appropriate rotations and translations. I then joined all 4 objects into one. As you can see from my second screenshot, I got a difference, not a union, as expected.

One thing I would suggest for you to do is enable the "3D Print Tools" add-on and check your mesh for degenerate topology.

[image: Check for degenerate topology]

[image: Final output]

Comment: I have checked the degenerate topology on the 3d print tools, but no matter what I set it to it gives me the same result.